# Black screen when playing video on Android 4.4 (API 19) kitkat

Tags: android, react-native, android-4.4-kitkat, android-9.0-pie, react-native-video

Im using [react-native-video](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-video) with react-native. I need to install and run this on an older Android version **Android 4.4 (API 19) kitkat**.

But Im only getting a black screen when playing video on Android 4.4 (API 19). Not sure what is happening. Works fine on **Android 9 (API 28)**

Is the library not supported on Android 4.4?

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <View>
        <Video
          source={require('./assets/backgroundVideo.mp4')}
          ref={(ref) => {
            this.player = ref
          }}                                      
          onBuffer={this.onBuffer}                
          onError={this.videoError}               
          style={styles.backgroundVideo} />
      </View>
    </Fragment>
  );
};
```

**UPDATE:**
Im also getting the same error in Android studio using the mediaplayer library.

I read this https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats so I changed the profile in my encoding from H.264 AVC Main Profile to H.264 AVC Baseline Profile (BP). But no difference.

Im testing on emulator via android studio. I have got no device with that os. Android 4.4 Version.api: 19 (Google API) and resolution 1920 x 1080

Comment: Which version of react-native-video?

Comment: version 4.4.4
I just tried as well running on mediaplayer built in Android studio. Got the same problem there. Could it possibly be a codec problem/ video format? Im using .mp4

Comment: .mp4 is just a container. What is the actual video stream format?

Comment: When Im opening the file in VLC and choosing codec information i get:
H264 - MPEG-4 AVC (part 10)(avc1)

I guess it is that?

Comment: @acroscene That seems like normal H264, what is the size (HxW) and how are you testing on Kitkat (emulator or device, list specs).

Comment: I read this: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats#video-codecs .... so I changed the profile in my encoding from H.264 AVC Main Profile to H.264 AVC Baseline Profile (BP). But no difference. Im testing on emulator via android studio. I have got no device with that os. Android 4.4 Version.api: 19 (Google API) and resolution 1920 x 1080

Answer (score 0):

Per the [exoplayer](https://exoplayer.dev/supported-devices.html) website, if you're using an emulator, it at least needs api version 23.